# Unable to refresh listView from other class

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-dialogfragment

In my main fragment, I have a listView called `notesListView`. `noteAdapter` populates `notesListView`. When user long clicks on one of the `notesListView`'s elements, a dialog shows up and asks if user really wants to remove an item. If he agrees, then that item is removed from the database. If not - then life goes on.

The issue is that my Dialog is other class (other Fragment). For this class, I pass my `database` object and `noteAdapter` object as well, so it could remove item from database and then notify `noteAdapter` that data has changed. Sounds good enough, but it doesn't work, and I have absolutely no idea why. Give it a look please and help me out.

This is a method in mainFragment, which handles the mentioned listView:

public void handleNotes(final ListView notesListView) {

```
if (database.getNoteCount() != 0) {
    notesListView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);

    notesListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            TextView textViewId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);

            DeleteNoteFragment newFragment = new DeleteNoteFragment(database, noteAdapter, Integer.parseInt(textViewId.getText().toString()));
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "deleteConfirmation");

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

As you can see, DeleteNoteFragment is being created and then shown.
Lets look at DeleteNoteFragment itself:

```
public class DeleteNoteFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private Database database;
    private NoteAdapter noteAdapter;
    private int i;

    public DeleteNoteFragment(Database database, NoteAdapter noteAdapter, int i) {
        this.database = database;
        this.noteAdapter = noteAdapter;
        this.i = i;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_delete_note)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_delete_confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        database.removeNote(i);
                        noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Note deleted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_delete_denny, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }


}
```

Maybe you can spot where I am making a mistake, or got any tips how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deleting the data in database but not in the adapter:

```
database.removeNote(i);
noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Creates a method in the adapter to get the list that you have in the adapter. Something like:

```
database.removeNote(i);
noteAdapter.getListOfItems().remove(i);
noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

`notifyDataSetChanged` - "Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself." It doesn't reload data from database. You still have to remove the item from the adapter by calling `remove` method and then call `notifyDataSetChanged`